# Like Button Title

Tags: button, facebook-like

i've a script that list 2-3 articles with their Like Button.

Removing the og:url tag from the page solved the problem of the url displayed on facebook.

There is a way to tell to each button the title to display instead of the generic page title?

e.g.:

page title: Search Result.

first button: result 1 title

second button: result 2 title, etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The page title comes from the URL that you are liking - Try adding the og:title open graph tag to the pages that you are displaying like buttons for. Other than using og:title, there is no way to set the title that gets displayed.

Comment: I believe if og:title isn't provided, Facebook pulls the value of the `<title>` tag.

Comment: I believe you are right.